Where is the ibus-libpinyin's default system dictionary located?
ibus-libpinyin is  input method framework (builtin libpinyin support) for Chinese.Even if you do not create a user dictionary,you can still get Chinese phrases as output,there are many built-in dictionaries,

Where is the ibus-libpinyin's default system dictionary file(or maybe database file)located?
